# can i increase my height when i am 18?

Tags: exercise, stretching, calcium

Sir i am 18 yr old male, i wanna get taller, presently i am 5'8 inches (172 cms)
can i get taller at least 5'11 (180 cms) or 6 foot please
Most of my friends are 6 foot and i am the short one even after wearing tall shoes gives me (175 cms)
i just started doing some exercises,sprinting,hanging etc
just wanted to know if its worth doing these exercises and having calcium diet.
when is the last stage of growth for males.Please help

Comment: The only way to tell is have your growth plates xrayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can actively do to grow taller. Your genetics will ultimately dictate your height. When you stop growing is not set in stone. It comes down to individual differences.
Like someone in the comment section pointed out, you should get an x-ray to see if you growth plates have fused. After they fuse, there is nothing you can do.